# Python zeep change prefix of signature in SOAP body

Tags: python, xml, soap, zeep

Using Python Zeep library, I'm trying to add a signature to a soap message. There is one thing that I can not seem to figure out: The prefix of the signature Id needs to be 'wsu' and not 'ns1'.

Example of my current request:

```
<soap-env:Body xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" ns1:Id="id-dfg098-cc62-2d32-81ds-a2549502hssf">
```

But the format needs to be

```
<soap-env:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-dfg098-cc62-2d32-81ds-a2549502hssf">
```

I'm aware you can set a namespace prefix like the following example

```
client.set_ns_prefix("ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")
```

however as far as I have tried, does not help in this case. as this will not target the correct prefix.

I have found similar questions on the web regarding this, however they never gave any fulfilling answer. I'm new to SOAP, so I already apologise for my ignorance.

Comment: why do you want to change the namespace prefix? it is just a place holder for the actual namespace. as long as the receiving party is using a proper xml parser the namespace prefix does not matter for processing. the only "valid" argument could be human readability.

Comment: Basically because the error message states the signature on the body is not found. As I'm new to SOAP, I'm unsure of what is important. But you're saying it can not be the cause here?

Comment: you are correct, a different prefix that points to the same namespace does not result into an error. maybe you can use a tool like soapui to check your request if it is correct.

Comment: If you could show us what are you trying to achieve then we can help you in better ways.